# How to break current NodeRED flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I've created a custom node, which calls some GET requests with includes some async functions. I am throwing `node.error()` in the first function then the other functions, which depend on the first one, also throw an `node.error()`. My question is: How is it possible to skip the rest of the code, so that there is no other function calling and no further errors?

This is for the currently latest version of NodeRED `v0.20.7`. I've tried to throw an Error, but this breaks/stops the whole server.

```
var jsonData, keycount;
await getJSONContent(plusURL)
  .then((data) => {
    jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    keycount = Object.keys(jsonData).length;
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    node.error(e); //want to break after this error message
  });

//Getting undefined, because function threw error
var itemNumber = getItemNumber(jsonData, keycount, config.name);
```

I wanted to break after the error message, so that NodeRED doesn`t send further error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the message passing down the flow after you have thrown an error then you need to make sure you don't call `node.send()` after you throw the error.

You can probably do this by inserting a `return` somewhere suitable (you've not provided enough context to the code for me to suggest somewhere)

Comment: I can't insert a `return` in the code because this is my function to `registerType`.

Comment: If this is in the node initialise code, then the best you can do is remove the `node.on('input',...)` callback so the node will not process any incoming messages.

Comment: I want the node to process incoming messages, until an error throws. When an error throws the node should stop and not send any other messages.

Comment: Then the code throwing the error is not in the initialiser, it has to be in the `node.on('input`,...)` callback and in that case set a node level variable and use it to gate the call to `node.send(msg)`

Comment: But my `node.on('input',...)` is in the initialiser. Where should I put this event listener else?

Comment: the `node.on('input',...) ` is configured in the initialiser, but it's not logically there. Anyway my point still stands, if you want to stop the flow at this point, you need to make sure you don't call `node.send()` (or call it with a null `msg`) after the error occurs.